# Customizing a permalink

Tags: permalinks, navigation

Good Day All

I have a featured slider on the home page that can call a category from which it gets its featured content. Now, for each featured slider, I made a post with category 'featured'.
Now the problem is, that currently when you click on the featured slide, you get directed to its originating post with category 'featured'.

```
<h2 class="featured-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url($arr[$i]["permalink"]); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($arr[$i]["title"]); ?></a></h2>
```

Now, what I would like to achieve is to change that dynamic link (above) to point to a specific category, and the category it should point to is exactly the same as the title that makes up this link - (title = h2 featured-title text)

So the dynamic url should point to

```
http://siteurl.com/category/title in the above link...
```

Is that possible?

Thank you!
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<h2 class="featured-title"><a href="http://siteurl.com/category/<?php echo strtolower(str_replace(" ","",$arr[$i]["title"])); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($arr[$i]["title"]); ?></a></h2>
```